# User-enter values are not being stored properly

Tags: java

I'm making a grade book that asks what user wants to do, then asks for a selected name, then asks what grades they want to enter. It's coming out nicely, but I cannot get it to store and add the numbers that the users enter. It asks them to enter a number then enter `-1` to quit. Then it should add the numbers together and display them, but everytime the program outputs:

> "The total of the numbers is -1"

It doesn't seem to be storing any numbers except for the last number entered, which is `-1` because that's what they type at the end. Help?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Assignment3

{
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{ 
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    int homeworkGrades;
    int quizGrades;
    int testGrades;
    int choice;
    int total;
    double average;
    String name;


    total = 0;
    homeworkGrades = 0;



    System.out.println( "Enter 1 or 2: \n 1 - Average grades \n 2 - Quit" ); 
    choice = input.nextInt();


    if ( choice == 1 ) {
        System.out.println( "Enter the students name" );
        name = input.next();



        System.out.println( " What would you like to do? \n 1 - Homework grades \n 2 - Quiz grades \n 3 - Test grades " );
        choice = input.nextInt();



            while ( choice != -1 ) {
                System.out.println( "Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished" );
                homeworkGrades += input.nextInt();
            }   

            if ( choice == -1 ) 
                System.out.println("Total for homework grades is " + homeworkGrades ); 

                total = total + homeworkGrades ;
        }

    else if ( choice == 2 ) {
        System.out.println( "Exiting program" );
    }

    else {
        System.out.println( "Invalid response, exiting program." );

    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Please format your code so that it's indented properly and there aren't huge amount of spaces in between lines. It's hard to follow this way.

Comment: don't put a semicolon after your if statement `if ( choice == -1 );`

Comment: Agreed, your formatting is horrible. Do remember that you should be using spaces for indentation when submitting to SO (it doesn't deal with tabs as well as one would hope). Also you have an if statement that does nothing (`if ( choice == -1);` <-- You need to remove that semi-colon).

Comment: I edited his formatting to make it better... then he changed it back :(

Comment: `name = dylan.next();`  "I named my kid #7"

Comment: I write it spaced out because I find it easier to read, and I'm new to this :(

Comment: `if (choice != -1)` is currently *inside* the `true` branch of `if (choice == 1)` (and therefore always true as 1 is not equal to -1), and still does `;` (which is nothing). You've incorrectly indented the next 3 lines - these are NOT part of this `if` statement unless you include an opening curly bracket.

Comment: @Darkcobra94 Regarding the wide spacing being better for you: I use tabs for indentation when I develop my code, because typing and backspacing three (or whatever number of) spaces annoys me big time. But tabs are generally frowned upon when sharing your code, so I automatically change them to three spaces before publishing my code. You like the wide spacing, but it's generally not accepted in published code. Just something to think about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ( choice != -1 ) {
   System.out.println( "Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished" );
   homework = dylan.nextInt();
}
```

This loop will never exit, because the user's entry is put into `homework`, but you're testing `choice` in the while loop.

The fix:

```
while ( homework != -1 ) {
   System.out.println( "Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished" );
   homework = dylan.nextInt();
}
```

Also note that, as stated by @Jack and others, `homework` (which should *really* be named something like `iTotalGrades`) should be accumulating the input, not just overwriting with the next value. It also should not add the `-1` (thanks again to @Jack), which is not a grade at all. Meaning this is my recommendation:

```
while (iInput != -1 ) {
   System.out.println( "Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished" );
   iInput = dylan.nextInt();

   if(iInput != -1)
      iTotalGrades += iInput;
   }
}
```

There are other problems, as noted by others, but these two are big ones.

Comment: As I said, there are other problems. I'm specifically addressing the while loop not terminating issue. I'll edit my post to say that, but as others already have said it, it seems redundant (and not worthy of a down-vote).

Comment: Okay, I changed my code up, made it look better. 
In the user menu:
 System.out.println( " What would you like to do? \n 1 - Homework grades \n 2 - Quiz grades \n 3 - Test grades " );

How can I differentiate the system from taking -1 and adding that to the grades? I only want it as an option when you are finished typing in your grade.

Comment: If I'm understanding you, I've addressed exactly that in my answer. Maybe you are looking at an old version? Refresh the page. It's the same concept as putting the input into `iInput` instead of `iTotalGrades`, and not adding it to `iTotalGrades` unless it's *not* `-1`.

Comment: I'm going to try this and if I have any issues I'll post them! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
homework = dylan.nextInt();
```

with this:

```
homework += dylan.nextInt();
```

Your code to break out of the loop is also faulty. You are never updating the `choice` variable, so you won't ever exit the loop.

You also want to be careful that you don't add `-1` to `homework` when the user wants to leave the loop.

Answer (score -2):

You name your scanner dylan, and you only made one scanner but you use it multiple times. So you store all your variables of this whole program into dylan. So it is overwritting the variable