# getting a bunch of compile errors

Tags: java

Getting a very strange error. When I add

```
{
    while {
        System.out.println( "Enter homework grades, Enter -1 when done" );
        homeworkGrades += input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

I get about 19 errors. If i remove it, then no errors. I've spent quite a few minutes changing it up, but I can't seem to get it to work. The program simply asks if you want to Average grades or Quit, then asks for your name. Now I want it to allow a user to enter in the Homework grades to average, then it will ask for quiz grades to average, then lastly test grades. Then it will take those 3 averages and average those.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int homeworkGrades;
        int quizGrades;
        int testGrades;
        int choice;
        int total;
        double average;
        String name;

        total = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter 1 or 2: \n 1 - Average grades \n 2 - Quit");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter the students name");
            name = input.next();

            System.out.println("Grades will be entered in this order: \n 1) Homework Grades \n 2) Quiz Grades \n 3) Test Grades ");

            //here
            {
                while {
                    System.out.println( "Enter homework grades, Enter -1 when done" );
                    homeworkGrades += input.nextInt();

                }
            }

        }

        if (choice == 2) {
            System.out.println("Exiting program");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid response, exiting program.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post the errors...? Have you looked them up online? What are we, your personal debuggers?

Comment: `I get about 19 errors.` Ahhhhh, those classic 19 errors. Someone must be a Stephen King fan.

Comment: The fact is that when I added a line of code it gave me 19 errors. When I remove it, the errors go away. Thanks for the smart reponse, bye bye

Comment: You should give homeworkGrades a starting value.  It's a good practice to initialize variables.  As for the errors, they might have indicated your problem.  Compiler errors are meant to help you diagnose the problem, after all.

Comment: You should really read the FAQ and this [blog entry](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by Jon Skeet on how to write a proper question.

Comment: I got a letter in the mail.  It's 19 sentences long.  Can you tell me what it means please?

Comment: Rather than attack someone with a snarky response, you'd do yourself a lot more good by replying to the first comment by @SotiriosDelimanolis, with an intelligent and informative response. You really can improve your question, and doing so (either now or in future questions) will only help you get better answers here.

Comment: Refer to answers on your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733963/user-enter-values-are-not-being-stored-properly) as to what proper syntax should like for your `while` loop.

Answer (score 5):

You need to give the `while` loop a condition, such as:

```
while (homeworkGrades != something) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your while loop when to exit. Without this information, it can not know when to stop. It is also not correct coding to skip the condition.

Based on what you have written, this will give you what you are most likely looking for:

```
int grade = 0;
while (grade >= 0)
{
    homeworkGrades += grade;
    System.out.println( "Enter homework grades, Enter -1 when done" );
    int grade = input.nextInt();
}
```

I hope i have helped you to understand this more clearly. :)